# Plain Makefile C++ Project & Unit Tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, project-organization

I'm currently working in a large-scale C++ project, which happens to have a considerable amount of unit tests. Over time, build times started to get pretty lengthy, so I decided to re-organized my build strategy. I'm currently using **plain makefiles** and I have **no plans** on switching to stuff like Cmake.

The overall organization is as follows: the project is composed of multiple modules, which are made of multiple classes. Those modules are compiled into *static libraries* and those libraries are then linked to the project's applications and the **unit tests**. As far as `makefile` is concerned, I have no issue to build the modules and the applications.

The biggest challenge lies in the unit tests: you see, originally, I got the tests to directly depend on those *static libraries*, which means that any change on any module, would lead to all unit tests being rebuilt. At the beginning this was not a problem, but it became clear that this is not feasible given the current project scale.

After some trial and error, I ended up making the tests depend upon **individual object files**, which means whenever a module changes (and consequently its object file), only the tests depending on it will get recompiled. Of course, the test executable will have to be *re-linked* (since it depends on the *static libraries*), but that's just a tiny fraction of the time needed to build the entire tests suite.

For the most part, this solution works **but it adds the burden of manually listing dependencies for each test**. Below an example of how the tests are built:

```
1 : ...
2 :  # Add test dependencies here (.cc files only)
3 :  MODULES = LexicalAnalyzer SyntacticAnalyzer IntermediateRepresentation
4 :  MODULES_DEPS = $(addsuffix .o, $(addprefix $(BUILD_TEMP)/,$(MODULES)))
5 :
6 :  .PHONY: all
7 :
8 :  all: $(OBJ_FILES) $(MODULES_DEPS)
9 :
10:  -include $(DEP_FILES)
11:  $(BUILD_TEMP)/%.o: $(CURDIR)/%.cc $(MODULES_DEPS)
12:     $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MT"$@" -c $< -o $@
13: ...
```

It is important to note that each test file in the suite has its own `makefile` (and is stored in its own directory). Line 3 lists the dependencies of the test, where `LexicalAnalyzer`, `SyntacticAnalyzer` and `IntermediateRepresentation` are project modules. Line 4 converts the module dependency list into a full path to that dependency's object file.

This approach seems to work for my needs, but I can't help to feel like it is pretty error-prone and too dependent on file names. How would you organize a project like this? Is there another way to do it using **only plain `makefile`**? I'm not sure I can fully explain what I've got, but hopefully this will be enough...

Thanks!

Comment: What is the name of that test? Which class does it test? Why does it depend on three modules?

Comment: Good question: The test is called FrontEndFlowTest and it is a suite of tests to evaluate my assembler's front-end flow -> Lexical analysis -> Parsing -> emission of intermediate representation. It is a somewhat higher-level test, focusing on integration... It depends on those modules because its tests receive a raw assembly code and must process to properly emit a stream intermediate representation symbols. Hope this clarifies it :)

Comment: I'd recommend having each test cover no more than one module (if that), but otherwise I don't see what problem you're trying to solve. "Pretty error-prone"? *What errors do you observe?* "Too dependent on file names"? Make uses file names; you can group them together with variables, but at some point you must still tell Make which files you want it to handle.

Comment: The thing is, I could not find a way for the tests to know when one of its depending source file have changed (here I refer to the .cc files). That's because the tests are quite isolated from the rest of the system. They can however see that the headers have changed (I'm using the compiler to generate the dependencies on the header files they include). In that sense, I have to manually find out which are the source files each test depends on and add them to the MODULES variable. If I forget one, the test will not be rebuilt if some .cc file changes... not sure if there is a better way to do it

Comment: I don't understand why your test's object files depend on module's object files? In case module's object files change it is not necessary to recompile tests, just re-link them against new objects.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/cppfw/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Comment: You are not adding the names of source files to the `MODULES` variable, you are adding the names of object files. I see no reason to combine tests of source files belonging to different modules into one test.

Comment: @igagis: thats right. The issue was to get the tests re-linked in case the .cc files changed. Since originally I added the static libraries as the only test dependency, any change o any module would lead to all tests being rebuilt. My solution was to add that 'MODULES' variable: what it really does is to make the tests depend on object files rather than the libs. That means that if a module changes, only those tests that depend on them will get re-linked.

Comment: @KyleOliveira ok, but then you need to add dependency on those object files to the tests linking rule, not to the test compiling rule.